# r.recode batch processing (QGIS)

Tags: grass-gis, reclassify

The integrated batch processing tools from grass in QGIS are extremely usefull...at least in theory, in practice they are really underwhelming because most of the time they do not work for me, although single processing does the job.

For example: I have 36 single band GeoTIFF files with categorical data (15 classes; 0 thru 14). I want to reclassify each category into a new (double) value, thus using [r.recode](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.recode) (r.reclassify only produces integers). The recode rules I provide in an external file look like that:

```
0:0:0.0
1:1:0.2
2:2:0.3
3:3:0.6
4:4:0.9
5:5:1.7
6:6:2.7
7:7:5.0
8:8:8.6
9:9:15.0
10:10:27.3
11:11:50.0
12:12:89.9
13:13:154.8
14:14:0.0
EOF
```

It works when using this with single execution, when using 'Execute as batch process', I get an error message *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extent'*. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? When activating the batch processing, I only provide input file list, recode rules and outfile.